# Developing a Visual Studio Extension for VS 2005+

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vspackage

I am developing a Visual Studio Extension the I would like to be compatible with VS 2005+(2005,2008,2010,2012,2013 and eventually 2015).

I have been looking into the requirements for this to be possible and came across this Manual on doing it http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0082/ .
It covers a lot of the details on how to accomplish this, but I am lost when starting from scratch developing my first VS extension.

The Article says,

> developing VS extension packages requires the installation of Microsoft Visual Studio SDK for a targeted version of IDE, i.e. a separate SDK should be installed with every version of Visual Studio for which an extension is being developed.

Does that mean I need the 2005 SDK, 2008 SDK, 2010 SDK, etc.?

Also, I don't see anything about what version of Visual Studio has to be used. I found some other articles that mentioned versions, but they were related to 2010+ extensions.

I am assuming I should use the .NET framework 3.5 for backwards compatibility.

I have the following questions:

1. What version of Visual Studio I should create my project on?
2. What version of the .NET framework I should target?
3. What Visual Studio SDKs will be required?

Comment: i suspect you'll have a lot of trouble developing a single extension that works on all versions. if i were you I'd start with 2015 and 2013 and try to port it backwards. I'm sure you'll run into scenarios that are possible with 2013+ but impossible with ones before. This will cover the largest % of user base possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an arbitrary decision that you want your VS extension to be compatible with VS2005+. Why not VS2003+ or VS2008+?

Anyway, this is possible but very difficult because VS has changed significantly since 2005. Debugging and testing and the extension can be a nightmare. You'll have to keep track of which features are supported by which VS version.

To do this, you have to develop a [VSPackage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166424(v=vs.140).aspx). The article you referenced discusses VSPackages but barely says anything about compatibility.

Compatibility here cannot even be achieved at the source code level. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb166245(v=vs.90).aspx) with important parts emphasized:

> Most VSPackages that work in Visual Studio 2005 will continue to work
>   in Visual Studio 2008 without modification. Most services, entry
>   points, and events maintain compatibility, **but there are some**
>   **exceptions**, which are listed later in this topic. Programmatic
>   interfaces also maintain compatibility generally, but elements of some
>   interfaces may change and **require source code modification** to work
>   with Visual Studio 2008.

Even when [Microsoft doesn't say anything about compatibility problems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512930(v=vs.100).aspx), they have been cases where things were working in previous versions but mysteriously became broken in later versions of Visual Studio.

You'll have to use conditional compilation and compile the extension against each VS SDK version. Also the deployment model of the extension is different for different IDE versions.

My recommendation is to target VS2010+ rather than VS2005. That would be significantly easier and most developers are using VS2010+ anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio 2008 with the VS 2008 SDK targeting .NET 3.5 to create a Visual Studio Package that can run on VS 2005+. You will also need to create an installer for it.

If you don't have much need for VS 2008 support, it would be much simpler to target VS 2010+ using Visual Studio 2010 to create vsix Visual Studio Extension that is installable by itself.

Comment: It would be a very ambitious goal to create an extension which works with any version of Visual Studio (from 2005 and onwards). It´s not only the deployment of packages that changed over time...

Comment: I should be able to use the <InstalledByMSI> tag in extension.vsixmanifest   for installing with an msi on 2005 and 2008 and use the vsix for 2010+ right? I know there is more to it than that with settings, but that eliminates the vsix limitation. I'll be doing some testing today, so I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: @Daniel vsix and vsixmanifest are not supported and not recognized by VS 2005/2008.

Comment: If you create a package with VS 2008 targeting .NET Framework 3.5 it may not run on a machine with only VS 2005 (.NET 2.0) because of missing assemblies, WPF for example (using both CLR 2.0 is not enough to guarantee compatibility)

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I understand they are not supported and I would not be deploying those in the msi for 2005 and 2008. Please see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/10/27/vsix-and-msi.aspx for what I meant.

Comment: @CarlosQuintero I have seen your site on vsx and found some great examples, so thank you for sharing your knowledge and experience. I should have mentioned it, but I will checking that the .NET Framework 3.5 is installed and it will be required.